# How did swift make web requests

Tags: swift, python-requests

I`m a new swifter ,so can take me some help to use swift to make web requests,thanks.  Why can't it be reviewed and submitted。

```
//创建请求体
    let param = ["moblie":"18392387159"]

    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    var string = "json="

    let Str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
    //拼接
    string = string + Str!

    let Url = URL.init(string: "http://huixin.smartdot.com:9901/GoComWebService/restful/GoComeRestful/getResetCode")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest.init(url: Url!)

    request.timeoutInterval = 30
    //请求方式，跟OC一样的
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            return
        }
        else {
            //此处是具体的解析，具体请移步下面
            let json: Any = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            if let value = JSON(json)["status"].string {
                print("状态是：\(value)")
            }
            print(json)
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()
```

i write like this , why it did not work !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you modify the following code

data is not recommended mandatory unpack ,I am here only to help you find the problem quickly to deal with this problem

```
  do {
   let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
    print(dic)
  } catch {
      print(error)
  }
```

Error returned here is

`Error Domain = NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 3840 "No value." UserInfo = {NSDebugDescription = No value.}`

You may ask the parameters of the problem, check their own